# Scroll not working to UP

Tags: android, android-tv

I have the following situation, when I press the button up the control, nothing happens ... the scroll bar works only down and to the side ... Does anyone know the reason for this strange behavior?

I have a fragment, inside this fragment calls this layout.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/NestedScrollViewCategoria"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/IDExibeNomeCategoriaFilmes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white_greyish"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/IDExibeCategoriaFilmes"
            android:shadowColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            android:shadowRadius="2"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:paddingStart="5dp"
            tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/main_progress_filmes_categoria"
            android:background="@color/background_color"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.WhiteAccent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/IDCategoriaPesquisa"
            android:shadowColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            android:shadowRadius="2"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:paddingStart="0dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your Both recyclerView xml :

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
```

or in java code for both RecyclerView :

```
RecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: The solution for this is we need to used nestedScrollView instead of scrollview